# Recover data from old hard drives that have Ubuntu installed

Tags: mount, filesystem

I have an old internal hard disk (320 GB) with an installation of ubuntu on.

I have a USB to SATA converter and was hoping I could plug the drive into my laptop and pull some data off it. My laptop is currently running Ubuntu 18.04

I am having trouble mounting the partitions.

### FDISK

The command fdisk -l /dev/sda produces the following information:

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=623067134): Invalid argument
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 78142806 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbdb60d19

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 623065087 623063040  2.3T 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       623067134 625141759   2074626  7.9G  5 Extended
```

I am not quite sure what is going on here. It is a 320 GB drive, yet sda1 is apparently 2.3T.

sda2 does not appear in /dev and when trying to mount sda1 with sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/temp, I get the following error message:

```
mount: /home/mike/temp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

maybe the partition table has gotten corrupted, however, I actually have three other drives each with a ubuntu installation on, all presenting with the same error (the drives and version of ubuntu differ). I have verified the USB/SATA link with some windows drives that I was able to mount easily with the above commands.

### FSCK

The command sudo fsck -V /dev/sda produces:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sda] fsck.ext2 /dev/sda 
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open 
/dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is 
corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate 
superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sda
```

Please help...

Comment: Are you sure that the external HDD on a USB->SATA convertor would be sda? sda would normally be your own internal boot disk.

Comment: Yes, my laptop drive is /dev/nvme0n1. The device /dev/sda is only present (lsblk and in /dev) when the external drive is connected.

Comment: The correct `fsck` command would be `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`... not sda.

Comment: You might run `testdisk` on sda and see what it finds. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for help.

Comment: The correct `mount` command would include a filesystem type... `sudo mount -t type device dir`. See `man mount` for more detail.

Comment: heynnema - Thanks for the advice. Testdisk managed to rewrite the partition tables and I can now mount them no problems. Great tool !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the comments...**

Run `testdisk` on sda and see what it finds. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for help.

**Result:**

*Thanks for the advice. Testdisk managed to rewrite the partition tables and I can now mount them no problems. Great tool !*